# How can I push to 2 different Firebase projects in one javascript file?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am looking to be able to read from one database in one project and then write to another database in a different project. I am looking to do it both in the cloud functions and in the client side Javascript. Is this possible?

Comment: You are going to implement the same logic both in client side (JavaScript) and also as function in GCP? Can you elaborate that point?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Initialize each SDK with the project settings, and use them as you expect.

Comment: If you want to work with two projects then this might help:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/

Comment: @DougStevenson so I can just reinitialise firebase using `firebase.initializeApp(config);` with a different config object?

Comment: Yeah, it returns a different app object each time.  Use the return object to target the project.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks so much! Would this implementation work in cloud functions too? Since you originally don't have to initialise firebase?

Comment: Why do you say you don't have to initialize the Firebase admin SDK in cloud functions? (you do)

Comment: @DougStevenson as in, can I just do the same thing as `db = firebase.initializeApp(config);` like I have done in my client side JS or do I need to use the admin SDK?

Comment: You generally use the admin SDK with cloud functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to name your different instances (Apps as Firebase calls them); by default you're working with the `[DEFAULT]` App, because that's the most common use case, but when you need to work with multiple Apps then you have to add a name when initializing:

```
// Intialize the "[DEFAULT]" App
const mainApp = firebase.intializeApp({ ... });

// Intialize a "Secondary" App
const secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp({ ... }, 'Secondary');

// Intialize other App
const otherApp = firebase.initializeApp({ ... }, 'other');
...

mainApp.database().ref('path/to/data').once('value')
.then((snapshot) => {
    secondaryApp.database().ref('path/to/data').push().set({ ... });
});
```

[More examples here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#initialize_multiple_apps)

Comment: it looks like Google changed from "Secondary" to "other" as referenced here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#multiple-projects

Comment: @WilliamTerrill That is just a naming convention.